# deleting an array that stores pointers to some objects

Tags: c++

I am storing pointers to elements of a vec_A in an array `A* a_ptrs[3]`  .  Assume that vec_A will not be resized. So, `a_ptrs[i]` will point to the correct element.

My question is:

Suppose A* a_ptrs[3] is declared in a `class B`. Since it is not created using 'new' I am guessing I don't need to delete it in the destructor. Am I right??

```
class A {
      public:                       
             int getNumber();            
             A(int val);
             ~A(){};
      private:
              int num;
};    
A::A(int val){
         num = val;
         };             
int A::getNumber(){
    return num;
};

 int main(){  
    int i  =0;
    int num;    
    std::vector<A> vec_A;
    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        vec_A.push_back(A(i));
        }

    A* a_ptrs[3];        
    a_ptrs[0] = &vec_A[0];        
    a_ptrs[1] = &vec_A[3];        
    a_ptrs[2] = &vec_A[5];

    for (i = 0; i<3; i++){
        std::cout<<"\n: a_ptrs[i].getNumber() = "<<a_ptrs[i]->getNumber();
    }        
    std::cout << "\nPress RETURN to continue...";
    std::cin.get();    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you need to delete an array, be sure to do `delete[] foo;`, not just `delete foo;` (array delete vs. scalar delete).  As pointed out, though, no, you do not need it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, thats correct.  You don't need to use delete.  The only issue is if the vector is resized e.g. by calling push_back etc - but you called that out in your post.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `delete` is used only for variables allocated with `new`.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, since there is no dynamic memory allocation in the program.

My Suggestion is to use  vector.reserve() function to reserve the size of the vector which will improve program performance.

Basically when you add an element to CArray(MFC) or std::vector it reallocates necessary memory and copies the elements so it will lead to memory fragmentation and will degrade program speed.